# pandas select columns by index stored in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I searched stackoverflow, but didn't find a good answer.
Is there an easy way to select columns by index stored in another column?
Say I have a df

```
A   B   truth
123 132 0
213 231 1
312 321 0
```

what I need is

```
A   B   truth output
123 132 0     123
213 231 1     231
312 321 0     312
```

I tried df.loc[<column "truth" converted to list>], but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an efficient vectorial method, use the underlying [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array and fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np

df['output'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), df['truth']]
```

Output:

```
     A    B  truth  output
0  123  132      0     123
1  213  231      1     231
2  312  321      0     312
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` function:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: row.iloc[row["truth"]], axis=1)
0    123
1    231
2    312
```

Comment: `apply` would be inefficient, this create a temporary Series for each row

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you're asking. If you're just trying to select row 1 in your example because its 'truth' value is 1, you can use something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['123', '132', '213'], 'B': ['231', '132', '321'],
        'truth': [0,1,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df['truth']==True]
```

Where the output will be

```
    A   B   truth
1   132 132 1
```

If you're trying to do something else with the data, I'd be happy to help.